# inside container container file permission issue for non root user

Tags: linux, docker, permissions

I am extending a docker image of a program [from here](https://github.com/exo-docker/exo/blob/master/Dockerfile) and I want to change some configs and create my own docker image. I have written a Dockerfile as follows and replaced the server.xml file in this image:

```
FROM exoplatform/exo-community
COPY server.xml /opt/exo/conf
RUN chmod 777 /opt/exo/conf/server.xml
```

When I created the docker image and run an instance from the image, the running program of the container cannot access the file `server.xml` because its owner is the `root` user and I see the `permission denied` error. I tried to change the ownership in the Dockerfile by `chmod` command but I see the `Operation not permitted` error. The user of the running container is not the root user and it cannot access the `server.xml` file that is owned by the root user. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: permission issue, as mentioned by @David docker `copy` copy the file as a root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is actually just a config file, I wouldn't build a custom image around it.  Instead, use the `docker run -v` option to inject it at runtime

```sh
docker run \
  -v $PWD/server.xml:/opt/exo/conf/server.xml \
  ... \
  exoplatform/exo-community
```

(You might still hit the same permission issues.)

In your Dockerfile approach, [the base image runs as an alternate USER](https://github.com/exo-docker/exo/blob/master/Dockerfile#L132) but a [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#copy) instruction by default makes files owned by root.  As of relatively recent Docker (18.03; if you're using Docker 1.13 on CentOS/RHEL 7 this won't work) you should be able to

```sh
COPY --chown=exo server.xml /opt/exo/conf
```

Or if that won't work, you can explicitly switch to the root user and back

```sh
COPY server.xml /opt/exo/conf
USER root
RUN chown exo /opt/exo/conf/server.xml
USER exo
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the switch user capability and now it is Ok.